# convert key value pair array to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

i have a function that scans a directory and builds a key,value pair of all folders and their respective files in it.

```
const listNotes =  () => {
    const listing = [];
    try{
      const folders = fs.readdirSync(defaultPath);
      folders.forEach((folder) => {
        let v = fs.readdirSync(`${defaultPath}/${folder}`);
        listing[folder] = v;
      });

      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } 
    return listing;
  };
```

and this is an output of such scan

```
[ DailyTask: [ 'Chores.json' , 'Sunday.json'] ]
```

that is a folder called DailyTask containing 2 files.

How do i convert this structure to JSON.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(some_object_or_array)`

Comment: Your secondary snippet is not valid javascript object notation.

Comment: `listing` is an array. Arrays can't have string indices.

Comment: What JSON structure do you want? Do you just want a JSON array that's the same as your JavaScript array?

Comment: Do you mean `const listing = {};`?

Comment: @Taplar yes exactly the DailyTask isn't a string , it's just there....i don't know what data type to call it

Comment: Er, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that.  My comment was reflective of what Code-Apprentice said.  Arrays (`[]`) in javascript do not have string indexes.  So if that is an object the correct object notation would be `{ DailyTask: [ 'Chores.json', 'Sunday.json' ] }`

Comment: @Taplar so you meant i should do?
```const listing = {}```
and 
```listing{folder} = v;```

Comment: In the end it doesn't really matter; if you have valid code that composes the object/array you're looking for, JSON.stringify is all you need to turn it into JSON. Just do `console.output(listing)` to see the structure.

Comment: `const listing = {};  listing[<a variable>] = <a value>;`  You don't use `{}` when assigning the variable.  Bracket notation is used both for arrays and objects, if the "key" is a variable.

Comment: @Taplar thanks fixed, i shouldn't have used square brackets, that's where the problem came from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `listing` variable is that it's an `Array`. `JSON.stringify()` doesn't include all the keys in the array, just the order of items, such as `listing[0]`, `listing[1]`. In your case, you aren't really using `listing` as an array, you are using is as an object. You can just make it a `object`, and then when you call `JSON.stringify()` it will include the keys.

**Solution**

```
const listNotes =  () => {
    const listing = {};
    try{
      const folders = fs.readdirSync(defaultPath);
      folders.forEach((folder) => {
        let v = fs.readdirSync(`${defaultPath}/${folder}`);
        listing[folder] = v;
      });

      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } 
    return listing;

    //If you want to convert to JSON
    console.log(JSON.stringify(listing));
  };
```

Comment: thanks, yeah that was my mistake